# Python Word Count of Text File

Tags: python, function, text

I'm trying to get a count of the frequency of a word in a Text File using a python function. I can get the frequency of all of the words separately, but I'm trying to get a count of specific words by having them in a list. Here's what I have so far but I am currently stuck. My

```
def repeatedWords():
    with open(fname) as f:
        wordcount={}
        for word in word_list:
            for word in f.read().split():
                if word not in wordcount:
                    wordcount[word] = 1
                else:
                    wordcount[word] += 1
            for k,v in wordcount.items():
                 print k, v

word_list =  [‘Emma’, ‘Woodhouse’, ‘father’, ‘Taylor’, ‘Miss’, ‘been’, ‘she’, ‘her’]
repeatedWords('file.txt')
```

Updated, still showing all words:

```
def repeatedWords(fname, word_list):
with open(fname) as f:
    wordcount = {}
    for word in word_list:
        for word in f.read().split():
            wordcount[word] = wordcount.get(word, 0) + 1


for k,v in wordcount.items():
    print k, v
```

word_list = ['Emma', 'Woodhouse', 'father', 'Taylor', 'Miss', 'been', 'she', 'her']
repeatedWords('Emma.txt', word_list)

Comment: Can you please clarify what kind of help you are looking for? Do you need someone to find you sample that does that (off-topic on SO)? If you need debugging help - please provide input/output and what you've already tried to identify problem.

Comment: I'm looking probably for a sample that works. I'm pretty much lost on this one, currently it outputs every word in the file and the frequency of each, whereas I would like for it to only give the frequency of the words that I have in word_list that are also in the file

Comment: Too homework-y for me. I don't really like these specific types of questions.

Comment: Oh, it's most definitely homework. I've been attempting to do this over Thanksgiving break and now I have absolutely no idea how to do it because I can't look at it anymore.

Comment: Also, I'm not saying it has to be a sample code, it can also simply be a step in the right direction. I've tried multiple ways, and some have worked such as simply hardcoding if then elif statements with the words themselves, I would simply rather know how to be able to do it with a list instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want the frequency of only the specific words in that list (Emma, Woodhouse, Father...)? If so, this code might help (try running it):

```
    word_list = ['Emma','Woodhouse','father','Taylor','Miss','been','she','her']
    #i'm using this example text in place of the file you are using
    text = 'This is an example text. It will contain words you are looking for, like Emma, Emma, Emma, Woodhouse, Woodhouse, Father, Father, Taylor,Miss,been,she,her,her,her. I made them repeat to show that the code works.'
    text = text.replace(',',' ') #these statements remove irrelevant punctuation
    text = text.replace('.','')
    text = text.lower() #this makes all the words lowercase, so that capitalization wont affect the frequency measurement

    for repeatedword in word_list:
        counter = 0 #counter starts at 0
        for word in text.split():
            if repeatedword.lower() == word:
                counter = counter + 1 #add 1 every time there is a match in the list
        print(repeatedword,':', counter) #prints the word from 'word_list' and its frequency
```

The output shows the frequency of only those words in the list you provided, and that's what you wanted right?

the output produced when run in python3 is:

```
    Emma : 3
    Woodhouse : 2
    father : 2
    Taylor : 1
    Miss : 1
    been : 1
    she : 1
    her : 3
```

Comment: If you want to apply that to a text file, you can obviously just replace the variable [text] with the file you want, which you already seem to know how to do.

Comment: It doesn't seem to like this part:  for word in text.split():
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Here's what I have text set as: text = open('Emma.txt', 'r')

Comment: try this: outside of the loop, set "text = open('emma.txt', 'r')" like you did. then, make a new variable, example: "textr = text.read()". use that new variable, in the loop. i think it's because "text = open(...)" is a file, where as "textr = text.read()" is a string (which the code can read).

Comment: Still not working, I'll put in the entire text inside of the initialization for text to see if that works and see if that fixes it, then that should narrow down why it might not be working.

Comment: note that my example code is written in python3.x . If running in python2.x, remove the parentheses from the 'print' function. Example: 'print(x)' should be changed to 'print x'. that should be the only thing you need to change

Comment: Getting name 'counter' is not defined

Comment: Yeah I am currently running with 2.7 something I thnk

Comment: do you have 'counter = 0' under the first for loop? you can see the code running on python2 on this link: https://repl.it/B46T/0 . just click 'run'

Comment: I have it exactly like the way you have it, I copied and pasted it into my IDE (PyCharm 5.0 using Python 2.7.1) and it still is giving me an error. Suggest just using a different IDE?

Comment: try copy/pasting from https://repl.it/B46T/1 . copying from stackoverflow may affect the format

Comment: https://repl.it/B462/1 seems to work. make sure that 'Emma.txt' is the correct file path. For example, i had to type "/Users/.../Desktop/Emma.txt"

Comment: Oh my goodness, thank you so much! I'm not sure why I had so much difficulty with this but finally, it's done. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to deal with this is to use `get` method in Python dictionary. It can be like this:

```
def repeatedWords():
with open(fname) as f:
    wordcount = {}
    #Example list of words not needed
    nonwordlist = ['father', 'Miss', 'been']
    for word in word_list:
        for word in file.read().split():
            if not word in nonwordlist:
                wordcount[word] = wordcount.get(word, 0) + 1


# Put these outside the function repeatedWords
for k,v in wordcount.items():
    print k, v
```

The print statement should give you this:

```
word_list =  [‘Emma’, ‘Woodhouse’, ‘father’, ‘Taylor’, ‘Miss’, ‘been’, ‘she’, ‘her’]
newDict = {}
for newWord in word_list:
    newDict[newWord] = newDict.get(newWord, 0) + 1

print newDict
```

What this line `wordcount[word] = wordcount.get(word, 0) + 1` does is, it first looks for `word` in the dictionary `wordcount`, if the word already exists, it gets it's value first and adds `1` to it. If the `word` does not exist, the value defaults to `0` and at this instance, `1` is added making it the first occurrence of that word having a count of `1`.

Comment: Thanks, but that still shows the frequency of each. I've updated my original post with what my code is now.

Comment: @JohnCunningham Is there a list of words that you don't want to include?

Comment: No, but in the text file there are a lot of words other than the ones than I have in word_list. I only want to count for the ones that I have in that list. So I don't want to include the words that are in the txt files that aren't [‘Emma’, ‘Woodhouse’, ‘father’, ‘Taylor’, ‘Miss’, ‘been’, ‘she’, ‘her’]

Comment: @JohnCunningham Ahh, now I understand your question. Run another for loop for the list, `word_list` and use the get method and that should get you the count. Check my updated code.

Comment: So should I have wordcount defined originally before the function? If not when I try and run it it's a global variable if I do not have the for k,v etc. inside the function